# how to run app in background on devices that kill background services (like Xiomi)?

Tags: android, service

I have tried running a service in background. Have used Start_Sticky.
Basically this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44744284/8212603). It works in many devices fine but in some devices like Xiaomi Lenovo the service dies when app is removed from "recent app" screen. I have also tried deactivating power saver for particular apps and full system but that doesn't work either.

How do I make it work in those devices? I know its possible because some apps (like whatsapp) and games are able to send notification even when the app is not in "recent app" screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the alarm with 1min in the onTaskRemoved() method in your service class. It will automatically invoke after the 1min and restarts the service.

In service class

```
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
     Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourService.class);
     restartService.setPackage(Yourpackagename);
     PendingIntent restartServiceIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, restartService, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
     AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealTime()+1000, restartServiceIntent);
}
```

Comment: onTaskRemoved() doesn't work if you click on 'clear all' in recent apps.

Comment: If that is the case set an repeating alarm for every 10 mins.